# Delta and Gamma computation using the likelihood ratio method in Black Scholes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

**Context:**

We consider a geometric brownian motion: $$dS_t = rS_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$$ with $S_0 = x$.

And we are interested in the function $$ u(x) = E(g(S_T)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} g(s) p(s,x) ds $$

Given that the stochastic process is log-normal we have:
$$p(s,x) = {1\over{s\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}T}}}\exp\left(-{\left(\log(s/x)-\left( r - {1\over{2}}\sigma^{2}\right)T \right)^{2}\over{2\sigma^{2}T}} \right)$$
$$S_t = x e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t}$$
**Problem:**

We are interested in computing the first and second derivative of $u$ of the form:
$$ u'(x) = E(g(S_T) \delta(T,W_T)) $$
$$ u''(x) = E(g(S_T) \gamma(T,W_T)) $$

where we need to find $\delta$ and $\gamma$.

Using the likelihood ratio method, we have:

$$ u'(x) = \int g(s) \partial_x p(s,x) ds = \int g(s) \partial_x \log(p(s,x)) p(s,x) ds = E \left( g(S_T) \partial_x \log(p(S_T, x))\right)  $$
$$
\begin{align*}
\partial_x \log p(S_T,x) &= \partial_x \log \left( {1\over{S_T\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}T}}}\exp\left(-{\left(\log(S_T/x)-\left( r - {1\over{2}}\sigma^{2}\right)T \right)^{2}\over{2\sigma^{2}T}} \right) \right)\\
&= - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2T}\partial_x \left({\left(\log(S_T/x)-\left( r - {1\over{2}}\sigma^{2}\right)T \right)^{2}} \right)\\
&= - \frac{\log(S_T/x)-\left( r - {1\over{2}}\sigma^{2}\right)}{\sigma^2T} \partial_x \log(S_T/x)\\
&= \frac{\log(S_T/x)-\left( r - {1\over{2}}\sigma^{2}\right)}{x \sigma^2T}\\
&= \frac{W_T}{x \sigma T}\end{align*}$$

This result is right and can be verified, for example using Malliavin calculus.

**Now I have an issue when computing the second derivative.** I tried to be smart and avoid bruteforcing it:

$$ u''(x) = \int g(s) \partial_{xx} p(s,x) ds = \int g(s) \frac{\partial_{xx}p(s,x)}{p(s,x)} p(s,x) ds = E\left(g(S_T)\frac{\partial_{xx}p(S_T,x)}{p(S_T,x)}\right)$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\partial_{xx}\log(p(S_T,x)) &=\partial_x (\partial_x \log(p(S_T,x))) = \partial_x \frac{\partial_x p(S_T,x)}{p(S_T,x)} \\
&= \frac{\partial_{xx}p(S_T,x)}{p(S_T,x)} - \left(\frac{\partial_x p(S_T,x)}{p(S_T,x)}\right)^2 \\
\end{align*}
$$

So,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial_{xx}p(S_T,x)}{p(S_T,x)} &= \partial_{xx}\log(p(S_T,x)) + \left(\partial_x \log(p(S_T,x))\right)^2\\
&= \partial_x \left(\frac{W_T}{x \sigma T}\right) + \left(\frac{W_T}{x \sigma T}\right)^2\\
&= -\frac{W_T}{x^2 \sigma T} + \frac{W_T^2}{x^2 \sigma^2 T^2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

**However, this is not right.** The right answer is:

$$\gamma=-\frac{W_T}{x^2\sigma T} -\frac{1}{x^2\sigma^2T}+ \frac{W_T^2}{x^2\sigma^2 T^2}$$

Again, this could be proven using Malliavin calculus.

***Can someone tell me the issue with my calculations?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We in fact have that $W_T=\psi(S_T,x)=\frac{\ln(S_T/x)-(r-\sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma}$. So note
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln p(s,x)=\frac{\psi(s,x)}{x\sigma T},\qquad\frac{d\psi}{dx}(s,x)=-\frac{1}{x\sigma}$$
and we conclude:
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{p(s,x)}\frac{d^2p}{dx^2}(s,x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\psi(s,x)}{x\sigma T}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{\psi(s,x)}{x\sigma T}\bigg)^2\\
&=-\frac{\psi(s,x)}{x^2\sigma T}-\frac{1}{x^2\sigma^2 T}+\bigg(\frac{\psi(s,x)}{x\sigma T}\bigg)^2
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: $W_t$ does depend on $x$... What a stupid mistake. Thank you!